# Can you mark notifications as NOT seen and NOT read?

Tags: getstream-io

I tried to pass false but it doesn't seem to do anything. In any regards what I was really looking for was to unread / unseen. At this point it was mostly for testing purposes but I could see this becoming a feature in our system.

```
mark_read   Comma separated list of activity ids to mark as read, or boolean true
mark_seen   Comma separated list of activity ids to mark as seen, or boolean true

$results = $notification_feed->getActivities(0, 10, $options);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking activities as unread or unseen is currently not supported by Stream's latest API (v1.0)

Comment: I would love to see this feature.

Comment: Is this feature finally available?, I see the answer is form 2016 and the API seems to not allow it yet, but may be it is just me not able to find it?